# Buscar determinado número dentro de uma string mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Bom dia pessoal.
Estou com uma dúvida que não estou conseguindo solucionar.

Em uma determinada tabela de um BD tenho uma coluna que salva uma string da seguinte forma:

> 1,2,3,4,5 **Linha 1**
>   11,22,33,44,55 **Linha 2**

Agora em preciso fazer uma busca para selecionar apenas as linhas que tiverem determinado número por ex:

**Selecione coluna X onde contenha o número 2**

Tentei fazer a busca usando o codigo abaixo, porém ele está me retornando tanto a linha 1 quanto a linha 2, porém eu precisava apenas da linha 1 que é onde tem exatamente o número 2 e não da linha onde tem o número 22

```
$sql = 'SELECT `ativos` from `produtos` WHERE `ativos` LIKE "%'.$id.'%"';
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver esse problema?
Desde já obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte maneira usando o [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> Supondo que seu campo **ativos** seja composto de id's de relacionamentos tomei a liberdade de usar uma sql adaptada onde você recebe um **id**. Qualquer coisa alerte nos comentários se lhe servir ou nao.

```
$sql += "SELECT ativos from produtos WHERE FIND_IN_SET(" + $id + ",ativos)"
```

Comment: Funcionou retirando a parte "IS NOT NULL". Muito obrigado

Comment: Opa, resposta atualizada. De nada :D .

Answer (score 1):

Use o trecho abaixo. Ele vai considerar as vírgulas como separadores.

```
$sql = 'SELECT `ativos` 
from `produtos`
 /*Separadores no meio da sequência */
WHERE `ativos` LIKE '%," . $id . ",%' 
 /*Separadores no início da sequência */ 
OR `ativos` LIKE '" . $id . ",%'  
 /*Separadores no fim da sequência */
OR `ativos` LIKE '%," . $id . "'
```

Deve existir alguma outra técnica que resolva seu problema de uma melhor forma, mas essa creio que já faz o que você quer.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, pelo que eu entendi você precisa exibir apenas a primeira linha da sua busca, então altere seu código sql para:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `ativos` from `produtos` WHERE `ativos` LIKE "%'.$id.'%" LIMIT '1' DESC';
```

Obs: DESC lista pelo registro mais recente e ASC o mais antigo.

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso saber todos os registros que contenham o id dentro da string não somente 1 linha.